# create angular library from whole angular's app

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I work on angular 5 application that use material module as a UI interface, i create template for all my projects and i want projects use this application as a library and my changes to general part of template [sidebar, navigationbar] update on library and apply to all projects. is this a good pattern?  if this possible, how to do this in angular 5?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a reusable library
you can use **[ng-packagr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr)** ng-packagr is a node library that can compile and package a TypeScript library to Angular Package Format. it is commonly used for pulling components out of  CLI project and package them up  into a format that can be used within other Angular applications.
execute `npm install ng-packagr --save-dev`

Refer this [Building an Angular 4 Component Library with the Angular CLI and ng-packagr](https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e).

Comment: Hi if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.