# How can we configure webpack to build angular project with custom npm package,which are published with only ts files?

Tags: angular, webpack, package, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I want to add one custom module to my angular 5 projects, but that custom module published with only ts files, and while doing 'ng serve' compiler looking for js files, so how can I configure my web pack to run the app with a custom module.
Can you please help me in that?

Comment: is it published on npm? which module you trying to use?

Comment: @Vikas It published to npm through a private registry (client specific package). As it is a private registry package, we can not access this package using this _https://registry.npmjs.org/_.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50187228/5695162)

Comment: Thanks, Vikas, I will check this.